# Insert issue with stmt bind params

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have another issue with my SQL. Below you can see the code I am using:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$contactpersonname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contactpersonname']);
$departmentname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['departmentname']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title']);
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

$stmt = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO Contacts (Name, ContactPerson, Department, Title, EmailAddress) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?')");
$stmt -> bind_param("sssss", $name, $contactpersonname, $departmentname, $title, $email);
$stmt -> execute();


echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

For some reason, the parameters are not binding properly, and the database is only having '?' (question marks) inserted. I had the database insert data properly, but that did not have the binding parameters. A person told me that it leaves me vulnerable to SQLi, and hence I tried to make a transition to stmt. I have literally no clue why this is happening. If possible, please do help me out. PS. I read through the php manual for the stmt binding, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Remove the quotes around your placeholders `'?'` -> `?`.

Comment: Take the spaces out: `$con -> prepare` to `$con->prepare` then user the bind command as: `bind_param( $stmt, 'sssss', vars...)` and take out the quotes from the `?` on your query.

Comment: Thanks Guys!!!
It finally works!!!
:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote varchar literals in SQL. By surrounding your `?`s with quotes, you're preventing them from being bound. Just remove the quotes and you should be good to go:

```
$stmt = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO Contacts (Name, ContactPerson, Department, Title, EmailAddress) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```